# how do I set up the skin indices and weights in three.js

Tags: three.js

I am trying to figure out how to use `SkinnedMesh` in three.js.
I made a test copying a lot of code from the official example [here](https://skeleton-test.glitch.me/).
But I still don't know how to do it with more complex shapes. I saw that `SkinnedMesh` has a method called `.normalizeSkinWeights()`. I don't know if this computes the skin weights. I also need to know how do compute the skin indices.

**I also don't care if the solution is some algorithm**

Answer (score 1):

Normally, skin indices and weights are created in a DCC tool like Blender. There is no logic in `three.js` that can automatically derive skin indices and weights for a given skinned mesh.

The code you have adapted is from the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/objects/SkinnedMesh) and just a simple showcase. The code makes assumptions about the geometry which is not true for most other geometries.

`SkinnedMesh.normalizeSkinWeights()` only ensures that the total skin weights for a single vertex are always `1`. So in some sense, it just ensures consistent data.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clearing that up. But that still doesn't answer my question. Does blender export the skinning data with the model? How do I set them up in blender? How do I export from blender?

Comment: I'm afraid you did not mentioned Blender in your question. Anyway, exporting skinned meshes to `glTF` from Blender is possible. I suggest you read through existing Blender resources that explains rigging/animation.

Comment: What I mean is I have more questions from that answer

Comment: A tutorial on how to set those "weights" inside Blender https://youtu.be/dKZrzG5r13g

Comment: + found a Blender script to export those "weights" to a text-file: http://nathananozie.blogspot.com/2019/02/blender-skin-weights-import-and-exporter.html?m=1

Comment: For reference, I've also found a reference to "skinned mesh attributes" into the [glTF spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/glTF/specs/2.0/glTF-2.0.html#skinned-mesh-attributes) but I'm not sure it is supported by neither the [import/export Blender addon](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO) nor the THREE [GLTFLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=gltf#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader) yet...